# How to use three JS scene, copy the contents of meshbasicmaterial (such as color, map, envmap texture, etc.) to a new meshstandardmaterial?

Tags: three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gupra.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePfBa.jpg)

Hello! I want to put three JS scene, copy the contents of meshbasicmaterial (such as color, map, envmap texture, etc.) to a new meshstandardmaterial, keep the texture content, color and other factors unchanged, and only modify the material type. What should I do?

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different material classes have different properties so the safest way to copy the compatible configuration from one material type to another one is to copy each property manually. Meaning

```js
standardMaterial.color.copy( basicMaterial.color ); // color
standardMaterial.map = basicMaterial.map; // texture
standardMaterial.opacity = basicMaterial.opacity; // number
// ..
```

Properties of type `THREE.Color` or `THREE.Vector2` should be copied via the respective `copy()` method. Texture and number/boolean properties should be copied via the assign operator.